# Using CSS :hover to change style but only when adjacent to particular class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm experimenting with Bootstrap.js panels that can collapse. I'd like to see if it's possible to change styling of a panel-heading element but only when it's adjacent to a panel-collapse element. The selector below will change all headings obviously.

```
.panel-heading:hover {}
```

Because I'm trying to look ahead to see if the target element is followed by a particular class I'm not sure I see if CSS can support this.

```
<!-- This should change style of panel-heading when hovering over the panel-heading element -->
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse">
    </div>
</div>

<!-- This should NOT change the style of the panel-heading when hovering over the panel-heading element -->
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can only do it left to right not right to left so if you hover over the right panel no way to talk to the left one.

Comment: CSS always goes from top to bottom.. If you see your HTML. `.panel-collapse` comes after `.panel-heading` so a pure CSS solution isnt possible

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to currently do this in CSS3, however there is something being proposed in [CSS Selectors Level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/). This feature has been widely requested.

`Relational Pseudo-class: :has()`

Such that you could do something like:

```
.panel:has(.panel-collapse) .panel-heading {

}
```

Meaning, apply styles to all `.panel-heading` classes that are a child of `.panel` classes containing `.panel-collapse`

This is a great article on upcoming CSS Selectors Level 4: https://www.sitepoint.com/future-generation-css-selectors-level-4/

In the meantime, you'll have to use something like jQuery. You could add a class like `.panel-hoverable` to all `.panel` elements that contain elements with the class `.panel-collapse`